# Is there any way to print a preparedStatement to the console System.out.println

Tags: java, jdbc

I need a way to view the preparedStatement for debugging here is my java code that I wish to print the preparedStatement to the console for.

```
public class UnitTestDMUtility_Select {


@Test
public void testQUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS() throws Exception{

    UnitTestHelper helper = new UnitTestHelper();
    Connection con = helper.getConnection(helper.sourceDBUrl);
    Connection conTarget = helper.getConnection(helper.targetDBUrl);


    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(DMUtility.QUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS);
    stmt.setInt(1, 101);
    ResultSet sourceVal = stmt.executeQuery();
    //Here is the QUERY
    //select count(*) from tr_demand where demandtypeid=101
    stmt = conTarget.prepareStatement(DMUtility.QUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS);
    stmt.setInt(1, 101);
    ResultSet targetVal = stmt.executeQuery();

    assertTrue(helper.resultSetsEqual2(sourceVal,targetVal));

}

}
```

Comment: Why not just set a break point and read the value?

Comment: Please tell me more.  I'm not privy to that.

Comment: Have you never debugged in an IDE before? I'm going to assume you're using eclipse, but, there are plenty of tutorials for the other IDE's. http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDebugging/article.html#usedebug_breakpoints

Comment: He's saying run your java application in jdb, set a breakpoiont before running your application and when you reach the breakpoint take a look at the value of stmt.

Comment: If you're using any modern IDE, you can set a breakpoint to stop program execution and read your variables. If you're not, you should. And if you are and have never debugged a program I suggest reading various tutorials that your IDE will provide to learn how, prior to asking a question on debugging.

Comment: Do you have an idea which value is should look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I output my queries to a log file ( and console ) by doing the following:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(DMUtility.QUERY_CHECKBOTHPARTS);
stmt.setInt(1, 101);

//Write stmt to console: 
System.out.println(stmt.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

For query debug I usually use the library [jamon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/), it is a JDBC proxy that logs every statement is invoked